# Filter Function affecting other rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Have been using Google Sheets' Filter formula

```
FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, ...])
```

to copy rows with specified value .i.e. 'Approved' in the **Master Sheet** onto another sheet, **Approved List**.

However, once I edit any value in **Approved List**, the entire sheet returns an error.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: That's because `FILTER` is a function that returns an array. The data isn't *really* there. It's just displayed there. If you try to edit it, you're adding data to the edited cell in the **Approved List** sheet and the FILTER function can't overwrite *real* data with display data, hence the error.

Comment: I see, thank you for the very clear explanation. 

Is there a formula I can use to draw out editable data from the **Master Sheet** then?

Comment: I'm afraid there is none I know of. You may want to look into Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually created a free google addon that can move data from one google sheet to another. It can easily filter out rows based on a certain condition. I'd be happy to set it up for you if you share a spreadsheet with me that I can use to show you how to set up the report. Otherwise, you could also create the filter exactly how you did, but then copy all of the values and then select Edit -> Paste special -> Paste Values only. From then you could edit it. However, this only works if you are editing once instead of needing to continuously receive new data. My addon is able to allow you to edit as well as get new updates from the filter. Message me if you have any more questions!